# Existe alguma tag de declaração de expessões no Laravel Blade (ao invés de só imprimir)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Eu queria saber se existe alguma maneira de criar expressões com as tags do Blade do `Laravel`. Quero dizer, da mesma forma que usarmos `{{ $valor }}` para poder imprimir algo, seria possível usar a sintaxe do blade para declarar algo, ao invés de somente imprimir?

Por exemplo, alguns template engines permitem fazer algo parecido com isso:

```
 {% $valor = 1 %}
 {{ $valor }}
```

Tem como fazer isso no `Laravel`?

Comment: Não tem como, mas o Blade não restringe o uso de php em suas views. logo se utilizar <?php $valor = 1 ?>  {{ $valor }} irá imprimir 1

Comment: "Não tem como" é uma afirmação muito genérica. Ter como tem, pois o blade oferece mecanismo para você criar sua própria sintaxe, além de ter um pequeno workaround para isso.

Comment: Qual seria o uso dessa declaração? Realmente não tem como passar essa variável por referência?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode ser criado um [directive do Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#extending-blade):

```
Blade::directive("variable", function($expression){
      $expression = str_replace(';','=', $expression);
      return "<?php $$expression; ?>";
});
```

Para utilizar na `View`:

```
@variable(num1;1)
@variable(num2;'abcde')
@variable(num3;new \DateTime())
@variable(num4;array(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

funciona assim `@variable`, entre ***parenteses*** uma `string` separado por *ponto e virgula* `(;)` sendo que a antes da virgula é o *nome da variável* e depois é o *conteúdo/valor*.

Código gerado no [***PHP***](http://www.php.net):

```
<?php $num1=1; ?>
<?php $num2='abcde'; ?>
<?php $num3=new \DateTime(); ?>
<?php $num4=array(1,2,3,4,5,6); ?>
```

---

***Referencia:***

[Extending Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#extending-blade)

Answer (score 1):

Como já foi dito em algum dos comentários, o blade não impende ao usuário de usar as tags  php.

Porém, há aqueles que preferem ainda uma solução no próprio `Blade` - como eu.

## Maneira 1 - A gambiarra

Então, a primeira opção é fazer uma pequena gambiarra.

O `Blade` compila `{{ $valor }}` para `<?php echo $valor; ?>` - eu ja abri o código-fonte e sei que é assim.

A solução seria fazer isso:

```
{{ ''; $valor = 1 }}
```

Que seria compilado para isso:

```
 <?php echo ''; $valor = 1; ?>
```

Ainda seria possível usar a mesma gambiarra com a tag de comentários do `Blade`.

```
{{-- */ $valor = 1; /* --}}
```

A saída seria:

## Maneira 2 - Estender o Blade

Eu prefiro essa segunda forma, pois uma gambiarra sempre gera confusões e problemas, no futuro.

Podemos estender o `Blade` e adicionar ao seu compilador uma sintaxe nova. Isso é feito através do método `Blade::extend(Closure $closure)`.

Por exemplo, vamos definir que a expressão `{? $valor = 1 ?}` seja interpretada pelo `Blade` como `<?php $valor = 1; ?>`.

Basta adicionar a seguinte declaração no arquivo `app/start/global.php`:

```
Blade::extend(function($value) {
    return preg_replace('/\{\?(.+)\?\}/', '<?php ${1} ?>', $value);
});
```